# How to import Jackcess and its dependencies into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, jackcess

I am trying to install Jackcess because I am developing a web app that is going to store information in an Access database.

I've tried downloading multiple .jar files that all appear to be the ones i need (apache-commons-lang and apache-commons-logging) but after adding them to the build path i continue getting the same ClassNotFoundException.

The exception went away for the jackcess missing class but after repeating the process for the others I am still getting the same problem. Any help or direction to where i can download the correct versions of these .jars would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they being compiled into the jar correctly and/or in build path? Is it a compile time or runtime exception? Where are you currently getting the jars from?

Comment: @JamesConway im getting them here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonsloggingjar.htm and i have no reason to believe they arent compiling correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackcess depends on specific versions of two Apache libraries. As documented on the [Jackcess dependencies page](https://jackcess.sourceforge.io/dependencies.html), for Jackcess 3.0.1 you need to provide

- `commons-logging` version 1.2 ([link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar)), and
- `commons-lang3` version 3.8.1 ([link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar))

Comment: How do I get the .zip or .tar.gz files into .jar form ? I downloaded and extracted them but I'm not sure what to do now

Comment: @Gpsy - I have added links for the jar files.